# Migration to Parse Server (on AWS) and mLab for Android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I have an already running Android app that is using the Parse.com backend service. I need the application to call the parse server instead and use the mLab database. Can you show me code examples on how send data and get data from mLab (using Parse Server on AWS) in my Android application. The Parse server is up and running. I have already migrated my database from Parse.com to mLab. mLab and the Parse server are connected.

This is the code that I am using when I call the parse.com URL-

```
package com.gendertimerpro.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import com.gendertimerpro.logger.Logger;

public class Utils {

    public static String URL_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://108.xxx.162.xxx/MyApp/";
    public static String REGISTER = "user_register.php";
    public static String LOGIN = "login.php";
    public static String FORGOT_PASSWORD = "forgot_password.php";
    public static String CREATE_GROUP = "create_group.php";
    public static String SAVE_SESSION = "save_session.php";
    public static String GET_MY_GROUP = "get_my_group.php";
    public static String GET_ALL_SESSION = "get_all_session.php";
    public static String SEND_FEEDBACK = "send_feedback.php";

    public static String PREF_NAME = "gendertimerpref";
    public static String TAG = "Utils";
    public static String USER_EMAIL = "email";
    public static String USER_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static String USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static String GENDER_TYPE = "gender_type";
    public static String Two_Three = "two_three";


    // twitter
    public static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    public static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    public static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "is_twitter_loggedin";
    public static final String TWITTER_USER_NAME = "twitter_user_name";
    public static final String TWITTER_ID = "twitter_id";

    // USER
    public static final String PARSE_FACEBOOK_ID = "authData";
    public static final String PARSE_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String PARSE_OBJECT_ID = "objectId";

    // GROUP
    public static final String PARSE_GROUP_NAME = "name";
//  public static final String PARSE_GROUP_NAME_CREATE_GROUP = "group_name";

    public static final String PARSE_NO_SESSIONS = "sessionCount";
    //public static final String PARSE_GROUP_RATIO = "points";
//  public static final String PARSE_GROUP_RATIO = "group_ratio";
//  public static final String PARSE_GROUP_SCORE = "points";
//  public static final String PARSE_LAST_SESSION = "last_session";
//  public static final String PARSE_LAST_SESSION_JOINTEXT = "lastSession";

    // SESSION
    public static final String PARSE_SESSION_NAME = "name";
    public static final String PARSE_NOTES = "notes";

    public static final String PARSE_NO_OF_MALE_SPEAKER = "menCount";
    public static final String PARSE_MALE_SPEAKER_TIMER = "menTime";
    public static final String PARSE_MALE_SLOTS = "menSpeakCount";

    public static final String PARSE_NO_OF_FEMALE_SPEAKER = "womenCount";
    public static final String PARSE_FEMALE_SPEAKER_TIMER = "womenTime";
    public static final String PARSE_FEMALE_SLOTS = "womenSpeakCount";

    public static final String PARSE_NO_OF_THIRD_GENDER_SPEAKER = "thirdGenderCount";
    public static final String PARSE_THIRD_GENDER_SPEAKER_TIMER = "thirdGenderTime";
    public static final String PARSE_THIRD_GENDER_SLOTS = "thirdGenderSpeakCount";

//  public static final String PARSE_SCORE = "score";
    public static final String PARSE_PRIVACY = "public";
    //public static final String PARSE_RATIO = "points";
//  public static final String PARSE_RATIO = "group_ratio";
    public static final String PARSE_POINT = "points";
    public static final String PARSE_GROUP_ID = "group";
    public static final String PARSE_GEO_POINT = "coord";
//  public static final String PARSE_LATITUDE = "latitude";
//  public static final String PARSE_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    //public static final String TWO_THREE = "two_three";

    // FEEDBACK
    public static final String PARSE_FEEDBACK_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String PARSE_FEEDBACK_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PARSE_FEEDBACK_USER_ID = "user";

    public static boolean validateString(String object) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (object != null && !object.isEmpty()
                && object.equalsIgnoreCase("null") != true
                && object.trim().length() > 0
                && !object.equalsIgnoreCase("(null)")) {
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    public static String postRequest(String url,
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        String request = "";
        String result = null;
        try {
            Logger.e(TAG, "url:: " + url);
            for (NameValuePair nvp : nameValuePairs) {
                request += nvp.getName() + "=" + nvp.getValue() + "&";
            }
            Logger.e(TAG, "request:: " + request);
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
            // established.
            int timeoutConnection = 200000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds which
            // is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 200000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            result = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
            Logger.i("TAG", "result -- " + result);
            int maxLogSize = 1000;
            int start = 0, end = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= result.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
                start = i * maxLogSize;
                end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
                end = end > result.length() ? result.length() : end;
                Logger.i("TAG", "result str -- " + result.substring(start, end));
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    public static String postRequest(String url) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            Logger.e("TAG", "url:: " + url);
            /*
             * for (NameValuePair nvp : nameValuePairs) { String name =
             * nvp.getName(); String value = nvp.getValue(); Loggger.e("TAG",
             * name +"="+value); }
             */
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
            // established.
            int timeoutConnection = 200000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds which
            // is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 200000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            result = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());

            int maxLogSize = 1000;
            int start = 0, end = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= result.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
                start = i * maxLogSize;
                end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
                end = end > result.length() ? result.length() : end;
                Logger.i("TAG", "" + result.substring(start, end));
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    public static GPSTracker getCurrentLocation(Context context) {

        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(context);
        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            // double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            // double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            return gps;
        } else {
            // can't get location // GPS or Network is not enabled // Ask user
            // to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //method for checking if the password matches
    public static boolean checkIfPasswordMatches(String firstPass, String secondPass){
        boolean flag=true;
        if(!firstPass.equals(secondPass)){
            flag = false;
        }
    return flag;
    }

    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "Conex�o com a internet indispon�vel.",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static final void showMessageDialog(Context context, String title,
            String message) {
        if (message != null && message.trim().length() > 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(title);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        String expression = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        CharSequence inputStr = email;
        boolean flag = false;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

As you see I am not using Parse.initialize(aContext, applicationId, clientKey); How should i change this code to point to the Parse server

Comment: Did you set up your parse server yet?

Comment: yes i have, i just dont understand the code examples that parse is providing. I need an very easy exempel

Comment: Guess what, you are not using Parse :) Maybe, sometimes ago you did, but know your call are directed to http://108.xxx.162.xxx/MyApp/ so you have a that address your own webservice.

Comment: but al the data is saved in my Parse.com database. So somehow my app must be connected to Parse.com. Can you please give me an example on what i should do

Comment: when you migrated the DB from parse to mLab , you then get a mLab.mongo URI like .... mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds0nnn-a0.mlab.com:nnnnn

that is the DB connector to use on your replacement server ... see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#usage for connection the server to the DB instance at mLab

Comment: You have tofind what's connect to parse.It can be your app, in such case yo should look for Parse.initializein your code. Or it can be the webservice that uses parse in the background

Answer (score 0):

Well,

To use the parse.com website, you probably have somewhere in your code someting like this:

```
Parse.initialize(aContext, applicationId, clientKey);
```

You now need to replace this with

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(aContext)
    .applicationId(applicationId)
    .server(urlOfYourOwnParseServer)
    .build());
```

That's it... you're done.

Comment: Guess what, you are not using Parse :) Maybe, sometimes ago you did, but know your call are directed to http://108.xxx.162.xxx/MyApp/ so you have a that address your own webservice.

Comment: ah ok, how can i call the parse server instead? And where to put the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051047/how-to-access-parse-client-key-from-terminal @FlorianBurel