# How to access Parse Client Key From terminal?

Tags: android, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I have one Migrated Parse server right now with `Bitnami`. I have all the keys but I am not able to access it's `ClientKey`. I want to Implement that ClientKey at Android app for Push notification purpose. I tried to access files but I am not able to find it.

I checked with server dashboard as well not able to find. Can you tell me what is the location of file Which is containing `ClientKey`. Right now I am using Terminal for accessing the files. Can you tell me path or commands which is helpful in finding the `ClientKey`.

Answer (score 0):

as you probably know.. client keys are not required in parse server but if you still want to require client keys this needs to be done inside the parse server initialization.

so in order to set your client key you need to do the following:

1. Go to your parse server **index.js** file
2. Find the line where parse server is being initialized

> var api = new ParseServer({

3. Add your client key there and restart (or redeploy) your parse server

So your code should look like the following:

[image]